# Is there a direct way to get clear details on gcc acceptable option values (e.g. for -std) without grep-ing through irrelevant material?

Tags: c++, gcc, standards

The gcc (or g++) compiler has a -std option to specify the language standard to use for compiling C or C++. At the top level one can see that this option exists.

`gcc --help`

`-std=<standard>          Assume that the input sources are for <standard>`

However, different versions of the gcc compilers will have a different set of supported standards.

Is there a simple and direct way to ask for detailed help on just that option so that one gets the details about accepted standards, etc. for just that option?

I have done kludges in the past where I dumped exhaustive help about all manner of options and then tried to filter out just the lines I wanted by piping it through grep (see footnote).  I'm not asking for that.  I'm asking for a way to get the details for just the option one wants (such as -std) directly without any such ugly kludge.  (Besides being awkward, the ugly kludges become problematic regarding getting all the relevant detail lines, including those lines concerning the option that don't happen to include whatever search term one is using to filter without knowing the extent of surrounding help text.)

It's hard to believe there is no direct way to do this.  Surely other people must want to be able to get detailed information about some option without getting mounds of unrelated other stuff besides.  I'm hoping someone can tell me the simple method I'm missing.  It's not this...

`gcc --help=std`

`cc1: warning: unrecognized argument to --help= option: ‘std’`

---

*[Sedenion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3740047/sedenion) was kind enough to provide the following example of the grep approach, which some readers of this question may find helpful.

```
gcc -Q --help=c++ | grep "\-std="
```

If someone only wants lines containing a known string, something like this could serve, if one remembers all the arguments and syntax details.  If one wants other lines in the same entry for some gcc option, that becomes trickier since one doesn't necessarily know in advance what lines to capture.  (Remember that -std is the *example* of the more general need for a better help option.)

Comment: The manual? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options

Comment: I do not think that there is anything available to show the help for a specific option only. If you want to get an overview of the available standards specifically, maybe `gcc -Q --help=c++ | grep "\-std="` is viable for you?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you for the handy link to that manual page.  That provides a list of possible standards that a given version of gcc might support.  The question I am asking is about any direct way to know exactly which standards are supported by the gcc version that is running on the box that one happens to be using at the moment.  So, on one box the installed gcc might have c++1y but not c++14, but a different box might have a version of gcc that supports all the way up to c++17.  The answer is different depending on the particular gcc version being used at the moment.

Comment: That sounds like a nice feature request for the compiler implementers, but it might still not give the full pictures (see the language support [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html)). Perhaps you may find more useful some [feature test macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/User:D41D8CD98F/feature_testing_macros) (or [cmake-compiler-features](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html)).

Comment: The documentation is versioned so you find the docs for the version you have to see the options it has. [gcc 6.5 options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.5.0/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) as an example.

Comment: @Sedenion Thanks for that example command using grep.  Although I mentioned in the request that this is not what I'm looking for, some might find what you provided helpful.  So I've acknowledged your suggestion and have incorporated it into the text to give it more visibility.  Thanks again.

Comment: @RetiredNinja It's not looking good for the option I was seeking.  As a next best to have some Answer, how about if you write up an Answer that explains in three steps 1) How to get the gcc version. 2) That one can get to the grand list of documentation at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/ to find the appropriate version of the documentation, and 3) How one can get to the Index page for that version to find the full details for the desired option.  If nothing better shows in a few days, I can mark your Answer as accepted.  For now, this seems to be the best one can do for details on option X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, it seems that no one knows of a feature in gcc itself that would provide what I was seeking, i.e. a direct way to use gcc --help to get the detailed information about a particular option for that version of gcc.

I appreciate the comments by [RetiredNinja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920069/retired-ninja) that fall back on the web documentation.  Even though that is a tacit indication that the gcc command itself is not (yet?) up to the task, for now that does seem to be the next best general purpose alternative.

A general procedure could follow steps like these.

1. Get the relevant `gcc --version`
2. Use the version to find and click on the most relevant GCC Manual at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/
3. Find and then click on any of the links (toward the bottom) for either "**Option Index**" or "**[Index]**" (but **NOT** on the "Option Index" for the "Short Table of Contents").
4. On the Option Index page, click on the link to "**Jump to:**" the section for the relevant starting character.
5. If there are multiple choices for the same option word (e.g. 4 entries for "std:"), one can try what seems the most appropriate (and then try another if that doesn't have what you were looking for).

But wouldn't it be much more handy (and not even dependent on the internet) if one could just enter that option name in a single command, perhaps something more or less like the following?

```
gcc --help=optionName
```